# Expectation of sum of coin flips

Tags: probability, expectation

I have an exercise, which I think my solution is right but it doesn't match the given answer.

We start by flipping $N$ fair coins. Later, we take all the coins that showed $H$ and flip them again. Later, we do the same, and we go on until no coin show $H$. Let Y be the total number of times a coin showed $H$.
The question is about $E(Y|N=n)$.

My attempt was: Let $X_i$ - the number of flips that the $i$ coin shows $H$. Then $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{2}$

$E(Y|N=n)=E(\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i | N=n)=E(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i) =\sum_{i=1}^{n}E(X_i)=2n$

I can't find a flaw in my solution, though is "right" answer is n.

Comment: Is $N$ a random variable? Are $N$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: Yes, N is defined in another section of the question but is independent.

Comment: If $X_i$ denotes the number of heads before the first tail appears then $\mathbb EX_i=\frac12\times 0+\frac12\times(1+\mathbb EX_i)$ so that $\mathbb EX_i=1$. Btw, at first you are saying that $\mathbb EX_i=\frac12$ but in your calculation you seem to go for $\mathbb EX_i=2$.

Comment: N is defined this way: We take a fair coin and flip it until shows $H$ the first time. The number of flips is $N$

Comment: @E_K this is much different than what is in your question, "we start by flipping $N$ coins", I suggest you revise this.

Comment: Actually, @drhab has explained it correctly I think, thanks!